# Cambiar el dato que recibo por POST de un modal

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, modal, update

estoy con la edición de los pedidos a través de modal y AJAX.

El problema esta en que en la tabla de pedidos el campo "Producto" es un numero, pero en el modal saco el nombre del producto, ejp: Láser de Diodo" gracias a una query que realice para sacar el nombre.

Pero claro al mandar los datos por modal así:

Con esto lo mando al modal:

```
<td class="otrotdfgaz" id="Producto<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>"><?php echo $res['producto']; ?> <?php echo $res['alias']; ?></td>
```

Con esto lo imprimo en el modal:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click', '.pedido', function(){
                var id=$(this).val();

            $('#pedido').modal('show');
                $('#eProducto').val(Producto);
              });
          });
</script>

<input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont corpiii" id="eProducto" name="eProducto">
```

Arriba realmente hay más datos pero solo os pongo el que interesa. Ahora lo mandamos por AJAX:

```
<script>
      $(function(){
          $("#actPedido").on("submit", function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var f = $(this);
              var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("actPedido"));
              formData.append("dato", "valor");
              //formData.append(f.attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
              $.ajax({
                  url: "pedidos/act-pedido.php",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "html",
                  data: formData,
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false
              })
                  .done(function(res){
                      $("#mensaje").html(res);
                      toastr["success"]("Pedido Actualizado", "Mensaje")
                      //setTimeout(function () {
                        //     window.location.href = "ver-cliente.php?ID=<?php echo $res['IdUsuario']; ?>"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
                        // }, 1500); //will call the function after 2 secs
                  });
          });
      });
```

Entonces hacemos el update:

```
<?php include "../../conexion/conexion.php" ?>
<?php
  $id = $_POST['eIdp'];
  $producto = $_POST['Producto'];
  $factura = $_POST['eNumero'];
  $eFecha = $_POST['eFecha'];
  $eVencimiento = $_POST['eVencimiento'];
  $estado = $_POST['select2-1'];
  $tipo = $_POST['select2-4'];
  $total = $_POST['eTotal'];
  $referencia = $_POST['select2-3'];

  die()

  $results = "Update pedidos Set Numero='$factura', Fecha='$eFecha', Vencimiento='$eVencimiento', Estado='$estado', Producto='$producto', Tipo='$tipo', Total='$total', Referencia='$referencia' where id= " .$_POST['eIdp'];

  if ( !mysqli_query($mysqli, $results)) {
   die( 'Error: ' . mysqli_error() );
 }
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Entonces esto es lo que me hace el UPDATE:

```
eIdp: 4
eNumero: 342342
eFecha: 2018-09-12
eVencimiento: 2018-09-30
select2-1: 0
eProducto: **Láser DualWave**
select2-4: 1
eTotal: 300.00€
select2-3: DW002
```

Lo que esta entre asteriscos tendria que ser un numero para que funcione todo bien. Entonces no se como hacer una query en el actualizar el pedido para que saque el numero a través de el nombre que sale o bien a través del numero de pedido. Lo mismo es algo complejo de entender pero no se como detallarlo mejor. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale ya lo deje yo mimo solucionado.Lo que hice fue mandar la id oculta al modal y después por AJAX y la que imprimo solo es esta.

Aquí la enviamos:

```
<td class="tdfgaz" id="idPr<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>" style="display: none;"><?php echo $res['idPr']; ?></td>
```

Aquí la recibimos:

```
<script>
   var idPr=$('#idPr'+id).text();
   $('#eidPr').val(idPr);
</script>

<input type="hidden" class="form-control inputmiocont" id="eidPr" name="eidPr">
```

No se si es la mejor manera, pero ahí esta la solución.

Comment: recuerda que si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema; debes marcarla como aceptada para que sirva como fuente de consulta a otros usuarios, saludos

Comment: Si gracias, hasta dos días no me deja ponerlo como valida